# Facebook PHP 3.0.1 SDK API, getUser() always == 0! Why?

Tags: facebook

I have the following code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '###',
    'secret' => '###'
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

$user is ALWAYS 0, my AppId and Secret are both 100% correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've added the example to my localhost's virtual host, added my AppId and secret, and still. NOTHING!

Comment: do you ever redirect the user to the getLoginURL() ? Users have to auth your app before you can get their user id.

Comment: It appears something is wrong with my Facebook config, especially the fields where you put the site url and domain. Still investigating.

Comment: When I try this from localhost it works. But from mydomain.loc, it fails, even when I update the domain on Facebook

Comment: I've also tried downgrading to Facebook 2.1.2, using $facebook->getSession(), but still nothing, and yes, I am logged into Facebook.

Comment: yeah its not going to work unless you set the Site URL config setting to localhost or http://127.0.0.1

Comment: I have no idea what happened. I didn't change anything, the code just started working, miraculously???

Comment: ...but know after logging out, getUser still returns a value! What on earth is going on! I am about to take my hair out my scalp!

Comment: There appears to be some issues with the PHP SDK, https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/418

Comment: Make sure you update to the very latest SDK as well.

Answer (score 4):

make sure that you have an if condition to check for user status

```
$user=$facebook->getUser();
if($user)
//someactions
else
{
// redirect the user to login and authorize your application, if necessary
header('Location:'.$facebook->getLoginURL());
}
```

Please check the case of functions. I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes obviously, but there's no point moving on to the if statement if getUser ALWAYS returns 0. This is helpful, nonetheless, thanks for posting!

Comment: ...I mean my point is, I should be able to login on Facebook itself, then getUser() should pick up that I am logged in with Facebook.

Comment: Not quite. If your app isn't granted access to the user (whether it's you or anyone else) then getUser() should not return anything but 0. Once you authenticate (forward to getLoginUrl) then your app has access and should return a user.

Comment: Also, if you are already logged on and already authenticated the app, anbd still getting a 0 somehow, this way you will get an infinite loop of redirections.

Answer (score 1):

Just chek in your facebook [Your FB Application Admin Panel](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) if you put the right website url... LOCALHOST for testing purpose or your http://www.YOURWEBSITE.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once...
And I just managed to solve it by correcting the problem with my session

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: GEEEEEEE THIS ANSWER REALLY HELPS

Comment: @BeauGrantham How can you say that it doesn't helps you. I just found that Session FB-SDK is creating getting problem and this was solved by managing my Session properly throughout the session.